# Java: Retrieving object from the set just by computing its hashcode

Tags: java, hash, hashset

I have created the Event class. As you can see, both hashCode and equals methods use only the id field of type long.

```
public class Event {
private long id;
private Map<String, Integer> terms2frequency;
private float vectorLength;

@Override
public long hashCode() {
    return this.id;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Event other = (Event) obj;
    if (id != other.id)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

I will store the objects of this class in the HashSet Collection.

```
Set<Event> events = new HashSet<Event>();
```

Since for the hash computation only the field of the type long I'd like to retrieve the elements from the events hashset by computing the hash of the id. E.g.:

```
events.get(3);
```

Is it possible or should I use the hashMap for it:

```
Map<Long, Event> id2event = new HashMap<Long, Event>();
```

?

Comment: There are multiple weird things: `getClass() != obj.getClass()` but yet you cast to `SimpleEvent` and not `Event`. `Float.floatToIntBits()` on a `long` is also weird. The `hashCode` formula also doesn't make much sense (just adding 31?)

Comment: Isn't using `if (Float.floatToIntBits(id) != Float.floatToIntBits(other.id))` the same as `if (id != other.id)`?

Comment: @Thomas Mueller
Right remarks. It happened due to the previous name of the class and the types of the variables in it. I didn't notice it while changing the class name and the variable type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should *absolutely not* rely on hash code uniqueness. A `long` has 2<sup>64</sup> possible values; an `int` only has 2<sup>32</sup>. Therefore hash collisions are entirely possible. *Don't use hash codes as your sole equality test. That's not what they're designed for.*

Hash codes are designed to quickly get from a key to a set of *potential* matches, which are then checked more rigorously with normal equality.

(As an aside, I don't think it's a great idea to use `floatToIntBits` to compute the hash code to start with. Look at what `Long.hashCode()` does.)

EDIT: Of course, even if you *did* want to rely on that, `HashSet<E>` doesn't expose a method for getting an element by its hash code, precisely because it's a really bad idea in almost all cases... if you want a mapping, create a `Map`...

Comment: are there cases in which such approach would be acceptable, just curious, thanks

Comment: @ultrajohn: If you can guarantee *absolutely* that there will be no collisions, then it would at least be *correct* - but still not a good idea, IMO. (You can't do it with `HashSet` anyway, of course.)

Comment: No. A Set stores objects, and doesn't let you get an object by a key. That's what Maps do.

Comment: @Jon, all hashbased maps in java, besides (hashtable) do scramble the bits to 'improve' the hashing, so unique stuff doesn't really matter. floatToIntBits is ok (that's the impl. of java.lang.Float anyways, iirc). As floats are 32bits, you cant better general hash (they have less than 2^32 possible values too). HashMap's extra hashing looks like that `h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12); return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);` The extra hashing is needed due to pow2 sized bukets (otherwise too many collisions w/ standard hashes)

Comment: @Jon Skeet
Thank you for your comprehensive answer. 
Hereby I'd like to thank all other people who answered to my question.
I will use the HashMap.

Comment: @bestsss: My objection to `floatToIntBits` is more to do with the logic of it than anything else - fundamentally the data has nothing to do with `float`, so why bring that into things?

Comment: @Jon Skeet
In the first draw I had the float value instead of the long value. I let eclipse generate the hashCode and equals methods. Some time after I changed the field type from float to long by forgot to change the hashCode and equals methods.

Comment: @Jakub: That makes a lot of sense :)

Comment: @Jon, wow with such code I suppose I have precluded any possibility that id is actually a long. My bad. I seriously thought it was a float (thus the standard hash for, and I also expected it's an auto generated by eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a static class (eg:Utility), and create a method which can generate unique hash in it.But you must estimate that there are how many objects will be created in possible, and then create a algorithm to generate the unique to distinguish the objects. And also the hashcode method of the Event class should be overrided because you overided the equals method.

And use the map :

Map id2event = new HashMap();